# How to load color resource using Resource ID in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am building a HarmonyOS application and want to load color values that I have placed in the resources folder in `resources/base/element/color.json`. How can I load this color in my Java class?

In Android we can use the [`getColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getColor(int)) function for this:

```
context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorID);
```

What is the alternative for this in HarmonyOS?

Comment: In HarmonyOS you can get color as follow:

`new Color(getColor(ResourceTable.Color_purple));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may can refer to the following implementations：

1. color.json

```
{

  "color": [

    {

      "name": "primary",

      "value": "#FF0000"

    }

  ]

}
```

2. MainAbilitySlice

```
    public void onStart(Intent intent) {

        super.onStart(intent);

        super.setUIContent(ResourceTable.Layout_ability_main);



        ResourceManager resManager = this.getResourceManager();

        try {

            int color = resManager.getElement(ResourceTable.Color_primary).getColor();

            Text text = (Text) findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_text_helloworld);

            text.setTextColor(new Color(color));

        } catch (IOException e) {



        } catch (NotExistException e) {



        } catch (WrongTypeException e) {



        }

    }
```

​